# How to show $|2z^{3} - 4z - 3- i| \geq \sqrt{10} - \frac{5}{2}$ for $|z| \leq \frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

Assuming $|z| \leq \frac{1}{2}$, show that$$|2z^{3} - 4z - 3- i| \geq \sqrt{10} - \frac{5}{2}.$$

My steps are as follows:
\begin{align*}
|2z^{3} - 4z - 3- i| &= |2z(z^{2} - 2) - (3 + i)|\\
&\geq \bigl| |2z(z^{2}-2)| - |(3+i)|\bigr|\\
&= \bigl||2z(z^{2} -2)| - \sqrt{10}\bigr|\\
&=\Bigl| 2z \bigl||z^{2}| - 2|\bigr| - \sqrt{10}\Bigr|\\
&=\Bigl|\bigl|2| z ||z|^{2} - 2|\bigr| - \sqrt{10}\Bigr|
\end{align*}
So the minimum value is attained if $|z| = 0$, which gives us
\begin{align*}
& \left|\left|0 - 2\right| - \sqrt{10}\right|\\
&= \sqrt{10} - 2 > \sqrt{10}-\frac{5}{2}.
\end{align*}
Since the smallest possible value is greater than $\sqrt{10}-\frac{5}{2}$, we have the result.

Comment: Yeah there might be some typos, but can you spot how to do it?

Comment: Looks like someone was kind enough to edit it.

Comment: @Boots Several of those steps should be $\,\ge\,$ instead of $\,=\,$, and they all need to be justified. But, assuming everything checks out, your lower bound is *better* than (and implies) the required one.

Comment: When I substitute the |z| for $\frac{1}{2}$ is should be $\geq$ right. However $\sqrt{10} - \frac{7}{4} > \sqrt{10} - \frac{5}{2}$, so this works?

Comment: You also need to explain why if you want it to be a full proof. Same goes for passing from $z^2-2$ to $||z|^2-2|$. Once all those t's are crossed, yes, that works.

Comment: We're assuming I know the reverse triangle inequality here.

Comment: That the maximum is achieved at $|z|=1/2$ does not follow from the triangle inequality.

Comment: I don't understand what I'm trying to do in the last part with the substitution. Could you help explain?

Comment: I don't quite follow, either. Was hoping you would clarify.

Comment: Well I'm not sure how to use $\Bigl|\bigl|2| z ||z|^{2} - 2|\bigr| - \sqrt{10}\Bigr|$ and $|z| \leq \frac{1}{2}$ to get the result.

Comment: Could I say that the minimum value is attained at $|z| = 0$ which would make the thing $\sqrt{10} - 2 > \sqrt{10} - \frac{5}{2}$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72848/discussion-between-boots-and-dxiv).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on previous comments:

$$
\begin{align}
|2z^{3} - 4z - 3- i| &\geq \left| \,|2z(z^{2}-2)| - |(3+i)|\,\right| \\
 &= \left|\,\left|2z(z^{2} -2)\right| - \sqrt{10}\,\right| \\
 &= \left|\, 2 \left|z\right| \left|z^{2}-2\right| - \sqrt{10}\right| \\
 &\ge \left|\,2 \left|z\right| \left||z|^{2} - 2|\right| - \sqrt{10}\,\right| \\
 &\color{red}{\ge} \left|\,2 \cdot \frac{1}{2} \,\left|\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2} - 2\right| - \sqrt{10}\,\right| \tag{*}\\
 &= \sqrt{10} - \frac{7}{4} \\
 &\gt \sqrt{10} - \frac{5}{2}
\end{align}
$$

The **(*)** $\,\color{red}{\ge}\,$ step follows from the function $\,|x(x^2-2)|\,$ being easily verified to be strictly increasing for $\,x \in [0, \frac{1}{2}]\,$, and also lower than $\,\sqrt{10}\,$.

---

[ *EDIT* ] As a side note, I still can't quite guess what shortcut would directly (and, presumably, more easily) prove the particular lower bound proposed in the question. The above gives a *better* lower bound $\,\sqrt{10} - \frac{7}{4}\,$ $\simeq 1.41$ $\gt \sqrt{10} - \frac{5}{2}$ $\simeq 0.66\,$, but that's still far from the *best* lower bound of $\simeq 1.6 \simeq \frac{\sqrt{41}}{4}$ at $\,x = -\frac{1}{2}\,$ if one were to trust WA's [`min |2z^3-4z-3-i| where 0 <= |z| <= 1/2`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=min%20%7C2z%5E3%20-%204z%20-%203-%20i%7C%20where%200%20%3C%3D%20%7Cz%7C%20%3C%3D%201%2F2).